# custom font using @font-face in css not working

Tags: html, css, fonts, custom-font

I was trying to add a custom font in my website but it doesn't work.

I have a css file like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SFProDisplayLight';
    src: url("./SF-Pro-Display-Light.otf") format ("opentype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    font-family: 'SFProDisplayLight';
}
```

and an html file like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident cupiditate, 
iste qui dicta corporis sit, harum architecto, illo nobis quidem modi ullam enim 
blanditiis odio porro facere. Consectetur, officia repellat!
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that the custom font isn't applied

Comment: If you open the dev tools and check the Network tab, can you confirm that the file is getting loaded without any 404-error (or similar)

Comment: yes the file is correctly loaded without error. @cloned

Comment: If the "SF-Pro-Display-Light.otf" really appears in your network tap (you might not see a 404 log in your console)  - inspect your page and search for overriding css style rules.

Comment: SF-Pro-Display-Light.otf doesn't appears in network tab, I solved the problem by importing the font from www.cdnfonts.com